# C++ with Qt - Conversion of angle in radians to DDD°MM′SS.FFF″ string

Tags: c++, formatting, qt, number-systems

I had to write a function which takes an angle in radians and precision N as input and returns a string representation of its magnitude in the format `DDD°MM′SS.FFF″` where `FFF` is fraction of the second N decimal digits long.

As conversion of a floating-point binary number to a decimal string [can be tricky](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2011/06/29/here-be-dragons-advances-in-problems-you-didnt-even-know-you-had/), I've decided to not reinvent any wheels for generation of the `.FFF` part, and instead use some existing ones like `QString::number`. Here's the code I've written:

```
#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

QString angleMagnitudeToString(double angleInRad, int precision)
{
    const auto angleInDeg = std::abs(angleInRad*180/M_PI);
    auto degrees = static_cast<int>(angleInDeg);
    auto minutes = static_cast<int>((angleInDeg-degrees)*60);
    const auto seconds = ((angleInDeg-degrees)*60-minutes)*60;

    const auto secStr = QString::number(seconds, 'f', precision);
    auto secStrIntAndFrac = secStr.split('.');
    if(precision==0)
        assert(secStrIntAndFrac.size()==1);
    else
        assert(secStrIntAndFrac.size()==2);

    // Rounding on converison to string may have resulted in 60 seconds, which should be carried to minutes
    if(secStrIntAndFrac[0]=="60")
    {
        secStrIntAndFrac[0]="0";
        ++minutes;
    }
    // Carry to minutes may have resulted in 60 minutes, which should be carried to degrees
    if(minutes==60)
    {
        minutes=0;
        ++degrees;
    }

    const auto intSecStr  = secStrIntAndFrac[0].rightJustified(2, '0');
    const auto fracSecStr = precision==0 ? "" : "."+secStrIntAndFrac[1];

    return QString::fromUtf8(u8"%1°%2′%3″")
                  .arg(degrees, 3, 10, QChar('0'))
                  .arg(minutes, 2, 10, QChar('0'))
                  .arg(intSecStr+fracSecStr);
}
```

The code seems kludgy due to the fact that I had to "manually" process the possible carry from the seconds to minutes to degrees, but I couldn't find any better way.

Comment: I'd love to see an implementation of the reverse function, which parses degree-minute-second strings and returns a value in radians.  That would be especially useful to create a test of round-trip stability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice code - easy to read and well laid out.  No surprises in the code, apart from the need to clear up the carry from seconds to minutes etc.

Some small improvements:

- Although `M_PI` is in POSIX, if you want to be properly portable, you'll want to define your own π, perhaps as `4*std::atan(1.)`;
- You might help the compiler to hoist the value of `180/PI` if you re-write the multiplication as `angleInRad*(180/PI)` or `180/PI*angleInRad`.
- There's no checking that the degrees value is in range of `int` when casting.
- It might make more sense to represent the angle in seconds or minutes rather than degrees (compromising the range in exchange for easier handling of the modular arithmetic).

## My version

```
#include <QString>

#include <climits>
#include <cmath>

QString radians_to_dms(double radians, int precision)
{
    static const double PI = 4*std::atan(1.);

    if (std::abs(radians) > ULONG_MAX*PI/180/60)
        // out of range
        return "---";

    const auto total_minutes = std::abs(radians*(60*180/PI));
    auto whole_minutes = static_cast<int>(total_minutes);
    auto seconds = 60 * (total_minutes - whole_minutes);

    auto secStr = QString::number(seconds, 'f', precision);
    if (secStr.startsWith("60")) {
        // it rounds up - carry to minutes
        secStr = QString::number(0.0, 'f', precision);
        whole_minutes += 1;
    } else if (secStr.startsWith('-')) {
        // negative zero - shouldn't happen
        secStr = QString::number(0.0, 'f', precision);
    }
    if (secStr.size() < 2 || secStr[1] == '.')
        // zero-fill
        secStr.prepend('0');

    return QString::fromUtf8(u8"%1%2°%3′%4″")
        .arg(radians < 0 ? "-" : "")
        .arg(whole_minutes / 60, 3, 10, QChar('0'))
        .arg(whole_minutes % 60, 2, 10, QChar('0'))
        .arg(secStr);
}
```

```
#include <QDebug>
int main()
{
    for (double a: { -0.0, -3.1415926535897932384, 1.0,
                     59.999996/3600*4*std::atan(1.)/180,
                     1. * ULONG_MAX})
        qDebug() << a << " = " << qPrintable(radians_to_dms(a, 5));

    const double step = .000142857;
    for (double a = 0;  a < 10*step;  a+= step)
        qDebug() << a << " = " << qPrintable(radians_to_dms(a, 5));
}
```

I get reasonable output from the test cases:

```
0  =  000°00′00.00000″
-3.14159  =  -180°00′00.00000″
1  =  057°17′44.80625″
0.000290888  =  000°01′00.00000″
1.84467e+19  =  ---
0  =  000°00′00.00000″
0.000142857  =  000°00′29.46637″
0.000285714  =  000°00′58.93274″
0.000428571  =  000°01′28.39911″
0.000571428  =  000°01′57.86549″
0.000714285  =  000°02′27.33186″
0.000857142  =  000°02′56.79823″
0.000999999  =  000°03′26.26460″
0.00114286  =  000°03′55.73097″
0.00128571  =  000°04′25.19734″
0.00142857  =  000°04′54.66371″
```

I'm not sure whether it's much improvement over the original, but I hope it gives you some ideas.